# Winium C# - Retrieving 'Next' attribute is null using GetAttribute('Next')

Tags: c#, selenium, getattribute, winium

I am testing an WPF desktop application in which I want to check a value against a name field of next (or previous) element of current element.

Example: (element1) Quantity: (element2) 100

Here, I want to check if the next element (element2) of Quantity (element1) is 100 or not.

The following code for the above scenario is null or empty.

```
var element = driver.FindElementByName("Quantity");
string qty = element.GetAttribute ("Next"); // Next attribute value is 100 in Inspect.exe
```

Am I doing it wrong? or Is there any other approach for this scenario?

**[Inspect tool - details]**

```
How found:  Mouse move (269,94)
hwnd=0x00000000002D1650 64bit class="HwndWrapper[Prax.exe;;93a825de-2e06-4b56-9205-49c253040049]" style=0x16080000 ex=0x40000
Name:   "partattributerev"
ControlType:    UIA_TextControlTypeId (0xC364)
LocalizedControlType:   "text"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:221 t:81 r:340 b:105}
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    false
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
AcceleratorKey: ""
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  18148
RuntimeId:  [7.46E4.2498D96]
AutomationId:   ""
FrameworkId:    "WPF"
ClassName:  "TextBlock"
IsControlElement:   true
IsContentElement:   true
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:18148,providerId:0x0 Main(parent link):Unidentified Provider (managed:MS.Internal.Automation.ElementProxy, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)]"
LiveSettingProperty:    Off (0)
IsPassword: false
ItemStatus: ""
ItemType:   ""
IsRequiredForForm:  false
HelpText:   ""
ClickablePoint: {x:280 y:93}
Orientation:    0
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "partattributerev"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: text (0x29)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    normal (0x0)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:   false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:   false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:  false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:  false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:   false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    true
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available:    false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:   false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false
IsCustomNavigationPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPattern2Available:   false
FirstChild: [null]
LastChild:  [null]
Next:   "0 x 0" text
Previous:   [null]
Other Props:    Object has no additional properties
Children:   Container has no children
Ancestors:  "partattributerev" list item
    "" list view
    "Sample" window
    "Desktop 1" pane
    [ No Parent ]
```

From this, I need to get the Next or Previous attribute value.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML from the page so we can see it vs the code you have posted.

Comment: What's the inspection details for both elements?  At what you've pastes with the inspection tool the name is partattributerev  - that's not quantity object. I don't think the property of one object will return the next like you expect. You'll need to identify both objects individually or a collection of objects to iterate through